# Laravel Eloquent - take most recent n entries

Tags: laravel

I have a model `Login` with fields `userName` and `time`.  I'm trying to code in Eloquent having the last n people to login.

I have tried many variations on what seems to be the most straigtforward:

```
$logins = Login::groupBy('userName') ->orderBy('time', 'desc') ->take($num)->get() ;
```

Unfortunately, the dates are not the users' most recent logins.  If I remove the `orderBy`, the data makes sense, but at that point it's only sorted by userName.  It needs to be sorted by time to be the last n logins.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

It appears that as it is written above, the results are the date that the user FIRST logged in, and then giving the 10 most recent "first logins".
This means that the groupBy is keeping the date that is oldest.  I don't know how to fix it but perhaps this helps someone help.

**EDIT 2:**

Now using ceejayoz's suggestion, I have:

`$logins = Login::orderBy(DB::raw('MAX(`time`)'), 'desc')->groupBy('userName') ->orderBy('time', 'desc') ->take($num)->get() ;//->sortByDesc('time')`

And now it's providing the most recent user's who've logged in but for `time` its still providing their first login.  I can change my view from using `time` to ... something representing the MAX('time') (not sure what it would be titled), or use an `AS` to get it with a different name (tried it but I didn't get it to work).

Almost there! :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what order do they come back in if not in descending order of time?

Comment: When I remove the `orderBy`, it comes back alphabetical on `userName`.

Comment: Ok, I feel that was clear from your original question. What happens with the orderBy?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.
Actually it seemed weird and almost random, but its not- it's interesting. Updating above.

Comment: Wait, right about what?

Comment: I think if you remove `groupBy` method, you will get the correct result. `Group By` is generally used for aggregation

Comment: Thanks (again), Razor.  The problem is that people have logged in multiple times and, without the `groupBy` it doesn't remove the duplicates.  Unfortunately, right now its removing the later duplicates and leaving the earliest.  I want it to leave the latest and remove the earlier duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to order by the maximum value in the `time` column for a user's records.

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('MAX(`time`)'), 'desc')
```

Comment: Ah, so close now! Updating above for clearer formatting.

Comment: You'll need to do the same thing with the `SELECT` clause. Something like `->addSelect(DB::raw('MAX(time) AS maxTime'))`. Or, add an attribute to the User model that stores this for direct access.

Comment: Final answer: `$logins = Login::addSelect(DB::raw('*, MAX(time) AS maxTime'))->orderBy(DB::raw('maxtime'), 'desc')->groupBy('userName') ->orderBy('time', 'desc') ->take($num)->get() ;`  It's my first day with Laravel and I'd bet there's a more eloquent (pardon the pun) way to do this.  Another day!

Comment: OK, for whoever needs it, it appears you can remove the second `orderBy`.